# map is not a function in IE11

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-11, dropzone.js

I think a sneaky bug in IE11 is creeping in and breaking Dropzone. Line 1653:

```
key: "handleFiles",
    value: function handleFiles(files) {
    var _this5 = this;

    return files.map(function (file) {
        return _this5.addFile(file);
    });
}
```

In IE11, if you call `typeof(files)`, you'll just get object - not array. It does have a length property, but, little else. No map function. `files.map(...` throws an exception.

Comment: I'm seeing this same error in Safari 11.01, so it's not specific to IE11. It's working in Chrome, however.

Comment: (and thanks for this! I was hitting my head against a wall) :)

Answer (score 3):

I'm seeing this error in Safari 11.01, so it's not limited to IE.

If you're using jQuery you can shim this quickly like so:

```
key: "handleFiles",
    value: function handleFiles(files) {
    var _this5 = this;
    files = $.makeArray(files);
    return files.map(function (file) {
        return _this5.addFile(file);
    });
}
```

And just like that the files object becomes a legitimate Array with a map function, and everything proceeds to plan.

Note that a typical Polyfill won't fix this; IE11 does have an `Array.prototype.map` - it's that the data structure held in `files` here is not a proper Array.

Comment: Does `Array.from(files)` or `Array.prototype.map.call(files, function(file){...})` also work here? I can't test quickly, and it might be nice to have a non-jQuery answer, too.